# Efficient data structure for storing integers in a range?

Tags: data-structures, search-algorithms, integers

Say I'm constantly given integers from the range $[1,2^{32}]$ in a random order and have to store these so that when a duplicate arrives I can deal with it. By the end of this algorithm all $2^{32}$ values will have been treated.

What's the best way to store which integers have been treated so far so that we can search if the current integer is a duplicate?

Comment: While I generally agree with the questions D.W. is suggesting, in this case, since you say you know all numbers in the range will show up eventually, a simple bitmap is almost certainly going to dominate on all axes.

Comment: @D.W. The reason I didn't specify time vs. space being my main criteria is because I assume if there were two options to those ends we could consider both. As for how many integers, that's mentioned already; how much memory, that's included in time vs. space; what architecture, I would have thought the assumed architecture would be your run of the mill desktop Intel/AMD x86_64 processor unless you meant what microarchitecture they were using but I don't think that's relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you know you're going to have to deal with all $2^{32}$ values eventually, you're going to need at least $2^{32}$ bits of memory, one for each value. The pigeonhole principle means that there's no possible way to store all the information you need with fewer bits than this.

So I recommend **a straightforward bitmap**. In other words, a simple array of bits. When a new value comes in, see if the corresponding bit is on or not; if it's off, flip it on. This takes the minimum possible amount of space, and is extremely fast (since all you have to do is index into an array).

P.S. You need $2^{32}$ bits specifically because the numbers could appear in any order. This means that there are $2^{2^{32}}$ possible states the program could be in, one for every possible combination of seen and not-seen values. Representing this many states will always take at least $2^{32}$ bits. If you knew the numbers would always come in increasing order, on the other hand, there'd only be $2^{32}$ states to distinguish between (since all you care about is the highest value seen so far), so you'd need a minimum of $32$ bits.

Comment: If the values appeared in order, it would also be the case that we have to deal with all 2^32 values eventually, but somehow we only need 32 bits this time, so that argument doesn't work. It's passing through the halfway point with 2^32 uniformly random bits that is interesting

Comment: @harold It has to do with how much information we need to save. In this case there are $2^{2^{32}}$ possible states we need to distinguish between.

Comment: @Draconis There are $2^{2^{32}}$ possible states *because the values can appear in any order*. There are only $2^{32}$ states if the values appear in order. I was going to say almost exactly the same thing as harold but decided not to. Focusing on the pigeonhole principle without saying *why* or even that there are $2^{2^{32}}$ possible states is odd. It's like saying there is an infinitude of primes because of the pigeonhole principle. Your first paragraph is just weirdly and misleadingly written.

Comment: @DerekElkins Added an explanation of that

Comment: That last point about how knowledge of the order of the integers would decrease the required bits is a nice addition.

Answer (score 1):

If the integers truly arrive in random order, then a bit array is a good (likely ideal) solution, and would require 512MB.

In the real world, information may be unpredictable, but not random, so a number of data structures optimized for sparse information (including sparse missing information) could be more appropriate if memory usage is a concern. For example, a binary tree of run-length encodings.

Assuming that the integers do not arrive in a truly random order, then the more you know about the pattern, the more potential optimizations will be available to you.